# Why we insert self-energy subgraphs in external lines to cancel infrared divergences completely (like in QED)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, self-energy

[image]

Here we need to keep terms originating from the same line.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: Weinberg,quantum theory of fields,volume 1,page 543-544

Comment: What do you mean? Radiative corrections on external legs are part of possible histories that we should sum over.

Comment: Radiative corrections on external line should be avoided.

Comment: Well, that's the effective conclusion cf. the title -- not the starting assumption.